# Need help deleted RELEASE Flash Player ActiveX (windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

Hello sorry if it has been asked already, I recently installed the flash player debugger for windows 8.1 (internet explorer) but i forgot about backing up the release build, then i uninstalled everything and i'm stuck.

My 2 directories are both without the activeX plugins (RELEASE) version of adobe flash player for IE (internet explorer).

- C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash

I'm currently downloading fp_30.0.0.113 Archive (425 MB) i hope it include everything as well as the plugin for IE ...

If someone has a solution it would be welcome, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled ActiveX on IE for windows 8.1 and my problem is resolved ! for the people who has the same issue please follow the steps (i know lot of people has the same issue).

1. Go to https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html and select the latest version (Released 06/07/2018) Flash Player 30.0.0.113 (425 MB) it contain both RELEASE/DEBUG version and all plugins.
2. On windows 8.1 select "flashplayer30_0r0_113_winax" -> properties -> compatibility -> "Windows XP (Service Pack 3)
3. Navigate to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash" and rename the file"Flash32_30_0_0_113.ocx" to "Flash.ocx"
4. Restart Internet Explorer 11 and profit :)

Ps: If you can't install because you have issue with permission you will need to take the ownership of "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash".